# Hot Meta Questions link color is too bright & doesn't meet accessibility standards

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, sidebar

Links in the Featured on Meta/Hot Meta Posts sidebar are #0095ff, while other links on the page are #07c. Does anyone else think this looks weird? The sidebar links are the same color as the Ask Question button but for some reason the button pulls it off and the links don't.

> [image]

Given the background color of the sidebar, it doesn't look like it meets [accessibility standards either](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=0095FF&bcolor=FFF8DC) (if you need a reason other than aesthetics for this request). Trying to put the regular link color in the sidebar causes it to [fail most of the accessibility tests](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=0077CC&bcolor=FFF8DC). Even the normal link color on white [fails WCAG AAA](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=0077CC&bcolor=FFFFFF).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too happy about this change either. It kinda hurts my eye when I look at it.

Comment: My [ReduceClutter](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) userscript has been updated to temporarily fix this eyesore.

Comment: *laughs in stack exchange dark mode*

Comment: I was just ready to ask this :P

Comment: I agree with the contrast being low. My vision isn't bad. Well, I wear glasses but I do have them on and I still have a little problem reading the text in the screenshot on a standard monitor that is just a little over an arm's length away from my face (80-90cm, at a guess). Sure, the screenshot is slightly smaller but that just *highlights* the issue rather than *cause* it.

Comment: Yea, they're too blue for me too. It makes it annoying to read.

Comment: The Firefox Accesibility checker tells me that it *Does not meet WCAG standards for accessible text.* My eyes tell me "aaaaaarrrghhhh!!!!"

Comment: FWIW, the style to revert this back to what it was is: `.s-anchors.s-anchors__default.s-anchors__visited a:not(.s-link), .s-anchors .s-anchors.s-anchors__default.s-anchors__visited a:not(.s-link) { color: #07C; }` (though Sam's userscript uses `inherit`, which works, too).

Comment: This question itself is now featured in hot meta posts

Comment: I'm really surprised this change made it through any sort of testing, unless it was a change elsewhere that also did this. It's not pleasant.

Comment: It's Stack Exchange's new "nightlight mode" :)

Comment: The Hot Meta Posts box on Meta has titles in black, not in blue. Much, much better IMO.

Comment: Looks like it finally got fixed.

Comment: Marking this as [[meta-tag:status-completed]] because it looks OK to me now. My eyes have stopped bleeding.

Comment: @David *"I'm really surprised this change made it through any sort of testing, unless it was a change elsewhere that also did this."* Isn't the latter scenario precisely the purpose of testing? Specifically, regression testing? Granted, this is not something that Stack Exchange is well-known for doing...